# XPath to find specific rows and related values based on a passed parameter

Tags: xslt, xpath

I'm trying to grab the value from the lights node, based on a house number set in a parameter.  The problem is, based on certain conditions, houses may be in different row positions.

If the parameter being sent to me for the house number is House237, then how to I get the number of lights located within the `row-2-Lights` node?

Also, how do I do the same if the next run, the house number is House867?  Below is my HTML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<table id="neighborhood">
    <tr onmouseover="leave('1')">
        <td id="row-1-house">
            <div class="houseCol">
                <a href="#" onClick="goHome('867');return false">
                    House867
                </a>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td id="row-1-Lights">
            <div class="decimal">14</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr onmouseover="leave('2')">
        <td id="row-2-house">
            <div class="houseCol">
                <a href="#" onClick="goHome('237');return false">
                    House237
                </a>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td id="row-2-Lights">
            <div class="decimal">12</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: We can help you write an XPath, but you'll first have to say what's invariant enough in your HTML to work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following XPath-1.0 expression. The parameter is the 'HouseXXX' string, the child of the `a` element.

```
/table[@id='neighborhood']/tr[td/div[@class='houseCol']/a[normalize-space(text())='House237']]/td[contains(@id,'Lights')]/div[@class='decimal']/text()
```

The output of this is

> 12

In this example the parameter is set to 'House237'. How you incorporate the parameter into the XPath expression depends on your usecase scenario.

For example, in XSLT you would replace 'House237' with a variable like $HouseNumber to set the parameter.